# Handle MouseScroll in ZK

Tags: javascript, java, dom-events, zk, mousewheel

I want to handle Event of MOUSE scroll in zk but unable to find it. I can do it using JavaScript but I want to send the notification to server side, so that server can send data back to client. Is there any way to get that event in Controller. or do

```
comp.addEventListener(EVENTNAME,mylistener);
```

I want to know what must be the value of EVENTNAME above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try org.zkoss.zk.ui.event.Events.ON_SCROLL or org.zkoss.zk.ui.event.Events.ON_SCROLLING.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I could find, the ON_SCROLL event will only work if the item has a scroll bar; if you want to capture the mousewheel event, you need to do this in javascript, and create your own event.

Here's what I've done to capture a mouse scroll in a paging grid to advance the pages with the mouse wheel; the part that sends the notification to the server side is the following line:  this.getPaginal().fire('onPaging', nextPage)

```
<zk>
<zscript>Object[] o = new String[150];

</zscript>
<hlayout id="layout" vflex="1" hflex="1">
    <grid id="grid1" width="300px" autopaging="true" height="300px"  mold="paging" vflex="true">
        <rows>
            <row forEach="${o }">
                <label value="item ${forEachStatus.index}"/>
            </row>
        </rows>
    </grid>
</hlayout>
<zscript><![CDATA[

  {
    grid1.setWidgetOverride("bind_", "function(){\r\n"+
      "this.$supers('bind_', arguments);\r\n"+
      "var node = this.$n();\r\n"+
      "if (node.addEventListener)\r\n"+ 
      "    node.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', this.proxy(this.onMouseWheel), false);\r\n"+
      "node.onmousewheel = this.proxy(this.onMouseWheel);\r\n"+
      "}");

    grid1.setWidgetOverride("onMouseWheel", 
     "function(event){\r\n" + 
      "    var delta = 0;\r\n" + 
      "    if (!event) /* For IE. */ \r\n" + 
      "        event = window.event;\r\n" + 
      "    if (event.wheelDelta) { /* IE/Opera. */\r\n" + 
      "        delta = event.wheelDelta / 120;\r\n" + 
      "        if (window.opera) \r\n" + 
      "            delta = -delta;\r\n" + 
      "    }\r\n" + 
      "    else \r\n" + 
      "        if (event.detail) {\r\n" + 
      "            delta = -event.detail / 3;\r\n" + 
      "        }\r\n" + 
      "    if (delta) {\r\n" + 
      "        console.log('delta = ' + delta); " +
      "        var currPage = this.getPaginal().getActivePage(); \r\n" +
      "        var nextPage =  Math.min (this.getPageCount() - 1, Math.max (0, currPage - delta)); \r\n" +
      "        this.getPaginal().fire('onPaging', nextPage);\r\n" +
      "    }\r\n" + 
      "    if (event.preventDefault) \r\n" + 
      "        event.preventDefault();\r\n" + 
      "    event.returnValue = false;\r\n" + 
      "}    ");
  }




    ]]></zscript>
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
Imo this should be the accepted answer

Comment: Btw interested in where you found the documentation about that.

Comment: Hi @TheBakker, It's been a while since I've looked at that, but the following github project has a few clues: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel